# Parameters for RDL Report generated from Cub

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, business-intelligence, msbi

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and i generated my cub and i want to make a rdl report with parameters but when i preview the report i found that the structures of values are strange 
For example instead of seizing in a field of paramettre the value 148, I have to put **[PRODUCT].[ID].&[1.48E2]**

When I generate the report from the database of sql server directly it works but from the cube it does not work

How can i do to just put 184 rather than 1.48E2 and why i have that structure?

Comment: Can you share the parameterized query you are using as dataset in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your datasets folder in report builder or Visual Studio , click "show hidded datasets" , amend the query to reflect your requirements.

Comment: I use MS visual studio of SQL and when i create a new dataset whitch uses the cube as datasource , i don't have the habillity to write a sql query but i have to create a mdx query, so when i preview my report i have to set a id production like [PRODUCT].[ID].&[1.48E2].
In database , the id product is an integer (0,1,2....)

Comment: yes, the query should be writen in mdx, you need to populate member caption in dataset and link it to your parameter, paste mdx from parameter here and I will amend that for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the

> How can i do to just put 184 rather than 1.48E2

part, first of all, I think you meant 148, not 184. Secondly, it **is** possible to just pass 184, but that probably involves little change in the report's dataset. As you have still not provided the query for the report's dataset, I can't really help you on how to make changes.

Now coming to the

> why i have that structure?

part, it is because of how the DSV of your cube is written. In scientific notation, 1.48E2 is same as 148.

If you want to see the member to look like `[PRODUCT].[ID].&[1.48E2]`, you need to probably change the format of `ID` attribute in DSV.